# Polyfill for attachEvent removing dhtmlx attachEvent function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dhtml

I`m adding chrome support for our legacy product (ie8 support), 
problem is that i adding polyfill for attachEvent

```
if (!isIE() && Object.attachEvent == null) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'attachEvent', {
        value: function(event, func) {
            if ('string' !== typeof event || event.indexOf('on') !== 0) {
                return;
            }
                this.addEventListener(event.substring(2), func, false);
        },
        enumerable: false
    });
}
```

but  we are using dhtmlx 3rd party library,  that manages events with attachEvent function, 
so my polyfill overrides this function, what makes dhtmlx miss-function.

Any ides how can I solve this issue? 
I want to polyfill attachEvent but not to override attachEvent of dhtmlx 
Thanks!

Comment: why would `dhtmlx` manage events with attachEvent functions when it claims to be `JavaScript/HTML5 UI Component Libraries`

Comment: the problem that they manage events via function name "attachEven", its only same function name, wrap function for managing events, but not actually deprecated "attachEvent"

Comment: so what's the issue? if "they" have a function called `attachEvent`, wouldn't it work cross browser since "they" claim to be a modern UI component library? Why are you trying to polyfill the `attachEvent` method only in non-IE browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to check for `IsIE()` ... since only IE uses the non-standard `attachEvent` anyway

For other browsers, you could polyfill `EventTarget.prototype.attachEvent` - since this is where `addEventListener` is defined anyway

```
if (EventTarget.prototype.attachEvent == null) {
    Object.defineProperty(EventTarget.prototype, 'attachEvent', {
        value: function(event, func) {
            if ('string' !== typeof event || event.indexOf('on') !== 0) {
                return;
            }
            this.addEventListener(event.substring(2), func, false);
        },
        enumerable: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, but i still override attachEvent of dhtmlx.

Comment: @IgorKorchagin - are you sure? so dhtmlx add `attachEvent` function? where do they add it? which prototype(s)?